# Calling an async redux action creator on form submission

Tags: redux, react-redux, react-final-form, final-form

In a typical React/Redux app it's pretty common to use [redux-thunk and async action creators](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions#async-action-creators) to trigger an AJAX request and dispatch actions on start/success/failure of this request.

However, I can't find a way to integrate such a function with react-final-form. Its [redux submission example](https://codesandbox.io/s/x71mx66z8w) is using [react-redux-promise-listener](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-promise-listener) which dispatches an action immediately, but does not let me call my async action creator.

It is possible to integrate react-final-form with a redux app that uses an async action creator to perform the on-submit action? I would prefer not having to move my AJAX logic into the reducers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the form library cares about is that the `onSubmit` function returns a `Promise`. If dispatching your action created with your custom action creator can return a promise (perhaps via some middleware?), that’s all that React Final Form cares about. The promise listener library is more for side-effect middlewares, like Redux Saga.

Comment: Sounds like something that could be useful in the examples.. I think almost every tutorial to get into react+redux uses redux-thunk for ajax actions.

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution:

My Component:

```
export function submitEdit(dataPath: string, payload: ActionWithCallback<number>): ActionWithDataPathBase<ActionWithCallback<number>> {
return {
    type: constants.EDIT_SUBMIT,
    dataPath,
    payload
};
```

}

Action:

```
export function submitEdit(dataPath: string, payload: ActionWithCallback<number>): ActionWithDataPathBase<ActionWithCallback<number>> {
return {
    type: constants.EDIT_SUBMIT,
    dataPath,
    payload
};
```

}

ActionWithCallBack:

```
export interface ActionWithCallback<T> {
data: T,
callback?: ((errors?: SubmissionErrors | undefined) => void)
```

}

the saga:

```
function* update(action: ActionWithDataPathBase<ActionWithCallback<number>>) {
try {
    const formData: PeopleForUpdateModel = yield select((state: AppState) => get(state.forms, action.dataPath));
    yield call(ajax.put, `/people/${action.payload.data}`, formData);
}
catch (error) {
    if (action.payload.callback) {
        const errors = handleFormErrors(error.response);
        yield call(action.payload.callback, errors);
    }
}
finally {
    yield put(actions.changeValue("edit.isLoading", false));
}
```

}

The HandleFormErrors function parses my server response to accepted final form errors format [SubmissionErrors](https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/examples/submission-errors)