# Calling an API on React Final Form submission

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk, react-final-form

I'm using React Final Form, and would like to call an API when clicking Submit on my form.

I'm attempting to follow the "Async Redux Submission" [example](https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/examples) and getting stuck. I'm using the `MakeAsyncFunction` from [react-redux-promise-listener](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-promise-listener), and can see the Action defined in `start` getting dispatched, but struggle to understand what should be picking it up in order to do something with it - i.e. call this API I want to use.

Simplified form code below:

```js
<MakeAsyncFunction
  listener={promiseListener}
  start={'FORM_SUBMIT'}
  resolve={'FORM_COMPLETE'}>
  {submit_form => {
      return (
          <Form onSubmit={submit_form}
              render={({ submitting, handleSubmit }) => (
                  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                      <Paper>
                          <Grid container>
                              <<fields>>
                          </Grid>
                          <Grid>
                              <Button type="submit"
                                      disabled={submitting}>
                                  Submit
                              </Button>
                          </Grid>
                      </Paper>
                  </form>
              )} />
      );
  }}
  </MakeAsyncFunction>
```

I have a Reducer which can pick up this action, but I know it's bad practice to do things like external calls within Reducers so I'm steering clear of that.

What should I be doing to process that dispatched action?

I'm using the Redux-Thunk middleware to make my API calls, which are defined with Action Creators. These are fine elsewhere in my app, but it's hooking them up to Form submission I'm totally stuck on.

I've seen a similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51101038/calling-an-async-redux-action-creator-on-form-submission) but failed to understand the answer (even though it's by the library's author!), so I was hoping someone would be able to help me further.
I'm pretty new to React, and web development generally (C#.NET APIs and databases are more my field), so any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[Here is a simplified example on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-final-form-query-9m2hi?file=/src/MyForm.jsx)

Comment: would be nice if you can share some code .

Comment: I've added my MakeAsyncFunction and Form code

Comment: Yeah, a CodeSandbox would be worth a thousand words.

Comment: @ErikR. I've added a CodeSandbox link to a simplified example of the app. Hope that's ok, I've never used this before, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Swapping the order of your middleware in `createStore` seems to have fixed it?

`composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk, reduxPromiseListener.middleware))`

instead of

`composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(reduxPromiseListener.middleware, thunk))`

Do not ask me why. I haven't looked into these libs in 3 years.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean - I need something which listens to the dispatched action from the form submission, swapping the order of the middleware doesn't do that? Do I need to add something else in addition to swapping them?

Comment: As I said, I'm not sure why swapping the order worked.

It doesn't work for you?

Comment: I think there might have been some confusion - when I left it, the code sandbox was running fine. I went back to it today and it didn't load, someone must have changed it. I have now got it running. But I'm still confused, I'm not sure what you mean by "worked", changing the order of the middleware doesn't help me listen to and process the action from the form submission no. That's what I'm trying to actually fix.